# PHP - Missing hidden input after curl request

Tags: php, curl

I have a script to login into a page using my mail/password using curl.
Before this i need to parse a field to catch a value to send it into the post request, but in the get of the page before the post i can't see a field:

```
<input id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden" name="X-Tmx-session-id" value="ANY">
```

Is just possible see it in the browser.
Whats the problem?

Here my actual code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

Class WalMart{

    var $http_response;
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $cookie;
    var $post_payload;
    var $uri;
    var $re;

    function __construct($username, $password){
        $this->username = (string) $username;
        $this->password = (string) $password;
        $this->cookie   = '[WALLMART_COOKIES].txt';
        $this->re       = "#name=\"X-Tmx-session-id\" value=\"(.*?)\">#";
    }

    function get(){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0');    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $this->cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);    
        $this->http_response = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    function parse_params(){
        $this->uri = 'https://www2.walmart.com.br/login?continue=https://connect.walmart.com.br/connect/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://api-ws.walmart.com.br/api/webstore/auth/callback&client_id=walmart_webstore';
        $this->get();

        // Dont work bcause input X-Tmx-session don't exists in the response string $this->http_response
        if(preg_match($this->re, $this->http_response, $match)){
            var_dump($match);
        }

        // FIELD <input id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden" name="X-Tmx-session-id" value="ANY"> Don't exists in curl request
        var_dump($this->http_response);
    }

    function start(){
        $this->parse_params();

        /*
         * post_payload creation after parse params to post request
         * 
         */
    }
}

$walmart = new WalMart('my_mail', 'password');
$walmart->start();
```

Problems with the sent headers? Or addtional field required?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: May be they changed the code, because I do not see this input in the login form. If session is given after login - we can not check it without username and pass.

Comment: @Cheery this field exists before the closes of form. You can see in the firebug for example.

Cheers.

Comment: It is created by javascript, as it does not exist in the original form. CURL does not run javascript code.